# SVR hyperparameter selection and visualisation

Tags: scikit-learn, data-visualization, svm, data-analysis, grid-search

I am just a beginner in data analysis. I want to use 'Cross-validation Grid Search method" to determine the parameters gamma and C of the Radial Basis Function (RBF) kernel SVM. I don't know where I should put my data on this code, and what data type I should use (training or target data)?

For SVR

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,explained_variance_score
from TwoStageTrAdaBoostR2 import TwoStageTrAdaBoostR2 # import the two-stage algorithm
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Data import (source)
source= pd.read_csv(sourcedata)

# Data import (target)
data= pd.read_csv(targetdata)

# Sample Size
datatrain = data.sample(n=60, random_state=1)
datatest = data[~dataL.index.isin(data.index)]

# Merge training set data (source and target)
train = pd.concat([source, datatrain], sort=False)
train.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
datatest.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

# Variable input
X_train, y_train = train[['x1', 'x2']].values, train['y'].values
X_test, y_test = FL[['x1', 'x2']].values, FL['y'].values

# Parameter setting
#sample_size = [n_source1+n_source2+n_source3+n_source4+n_source5, n_target_train]
n_estimators = 100
steps = 8
fold = 5
random_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
sample_size = [350, 60]

#1  twostage tradaboost.r2
regr_1 = TwoStageTrAdaBoostR2(SVR(C=50, gamma='auto'),
                      n_estimators = n_estimators, sample_size = sample_size,
                      steps = steps, fold = fold,
                      random_state = random_state)
regr_1.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred1 = regr_1.predict(X_test)
print("MSE of regular two stage trAdaboostR2--model1:",sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred1)))


#Plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(y_test, y_test-y_pred1, c="black", label="TwoStageTrAdaBoostR2_model1", s=10)
plt.xlabel("CAR")
plt.ylabel("Err")
plt.title("Two-stage Transfer Learning Boosted Decision Tree Regression", loc='left', fontsize=12, fontweight=0, color="orange")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

for cross-validation grid search methods(best parameters):

```
# Cross validation grid search (best parameters) 
parameter_candidates = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
]
svr = svm.SVC()
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, c=5 ,n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Best score for data:', clf.best_score_)
print('Best C:',clf.best_estimator_.C) 
print('Best Kernel:',clf.best_estimator_.kernel)
print('Best Gamma:',clf.best_estimator_.gamma)
```

For visualization of parameter effects

```
c_range = np.logspace(-2, 2, 4)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-2, 2, 5)
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'],'C': c_range,'gamma':gamma_range},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': c_range,'gamma':gamma_range}]

svr = svm.SVR()
clf = GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid=tuned_parameters,verbose=2,n_jobs=-1,
                   scoring='explained_variance')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Best score for data:', clf.best_score_)
print('Best C:',clf.best_estimator_.C) 
print('Best Kernel:',clf.best_estimator_.kernel)
print('Best Gamma:',clf.best_estimator_.gamma)

# scores for rbf kernel
n = len(gamma_range)*len(c_range)
scores_rbf = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][:n].reshape(len(gamma_range),
                                                            len(c_range))

# scores for rbf kernel
scores_linear = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][n:].reshape(len(gamma_range),
                                                               len(c_range))

class MidpointNormalize(Normalize):

    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))



plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, right=0.95, bottom=0.15, top=0.95)
plt.imshow(scores_rbf, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.hot,
           norm=MidpointNormalize(vmin=0.2, midpoint=0.92))
plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)), gamma_range, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(c_range)), c_range)
plt.title('Validation accuracy')
plt.show()
```

When I used this code, I found the following output Heatmap plot!
[image]

But I am trying to get a Heatmap like this one
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Could you add more context to your question and what have you tried to so far? For example is it for regression or classification? Are you using some standard data set such as the [iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html) or your data?

Comment: Thank you. I am using my data for regression (Support Vector Regression). I classified my data into (x_train, y_train) and (x_test, y_test), then, now I had a problem to determine the parameters to start the analysis. Finally, I want to plot the heatmap plot for the C and gamma as shown in the attached link.

Comment: Is it possible to update your question with an SVR fit and the corresponding results? You should use your training set for the fit and use some typical vSVR parameter values. e.g. `svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=100, gamma=0.1, epsilon=.1)` and then `svr.fit(X_train,y_train)`. This will help us establishing where the issue is as you are asking where you should put the data in the code. Also if you made a start with grid-search, could you post that too?

Comment: I already don't have any problem with the SVR but why I need to use those suggested parameters `svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=100, gamma=0.1, epsilon=.1)` if I can determine the best parameters?

Comment: Using `tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'],'C': [10, 100]},{'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [10, 100],'epsilon': [1e-3, 1e-4]}]` and `svr = svm.SVR(), clf = GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid=tuned_parameters,verbose=2,n_jobs=-1,cv=5,scoring='explained_variance'), clf.fit(X_train, y_train)` I get some results for gridsearchcv. you could of course increase the granularity of the model parameters. Can you try these and if it's not working update the question with the error message? Once you have the best fit you could run the model on your test set to see the behaviour of the model on unseen data.

Comment: Thank you so much. My last question, what is your opinion about this results from your experience "Best score for data1: 0.085 - Best C: 1000 - Best Gamma: 0.001"? And I found the mentioned problem above for the Heatmap plot.

Answer (score 5):

The following code with some typical regression data should work all the way through:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV,train_test_split
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

class MidpointNormalize(Normalize):

    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))
    

X, y = datasets.load_boston(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

# Cross validation grid search (best parameters) 
c_range = np.logspace(-0, 4, 8)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-4, 0, 8)
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'],'C': c_range,'gamma':gamma_range},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': c_range,'gamma':gamma_range}]

svr = svm.SVR()
clf = GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid=tuned_parameters,verbose=20,n_jobs=-4,cv=4,
                   scoring='explained_variance')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Best score for data:', clf.best_score_)
print('Best C:',clf.best_estimator_.C) 
print('Best Kernel:',clf.best_estimator_.kernel)
print('Best Gamma:',clf.best_estimator_.gamma)

# scores for rbf kernel
n = len(gamma_range)*len(c_range)
scores_rbf = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][:n].reshape(len(gamma_range),
                                                            len(c_range))

# scores for rbf kernel
scores_linear = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][n:].reshape(len(gamma_range),
                                                               len(c_range))


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, right=0.95, bottom=0.15, top=0.95)
plt.imshow(scores_rbf, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.hot,
           norm=MidpointNormalize(vmin=-.2, midpoint=0.5))
plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)),
           [np.format_float_scientific(i,1) for i in gamma_range],rotation=45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(c_range)), 
           [np.format_float_scientific(i,) for i in c_range])
plt.title('Validation accuracy')
plt.show()
```

The granularity of the grid is very low but it takes some time run otherwise. Also the limits of the grid will need to be more educated that the ones I chose.

I'm not sure why you get the error you get but I kept things simple and initiated the SVR once in my snippet so you can see how it works. I've also used different lengths for the `C` and `gamma` arrays that's just to show how these parameters are carried through. Sometimes I find that if everything has the same length is difficult to see which parameter is responsible for what.

The final plot looks like that but this depends heavily on the range of the grid, its granularity and the dataset that you are working with. Also note that I change the parameters of the `MidpointNormalize` class you provided.

[image]

Comment: I am so grateful for your help and really appreciate your suggestions. After using your recommended code I found this error
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 32 into shape (13,13)`
for this code line 
`scores = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'].reshape(len(gamma_range), len(c_range))`

I used 
`C_range = np.logspace(-2, 10, 13)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-9, 3, 13)`

Comment: That probably means the fit didn't update as with your input ranges `clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']` it should have dimensions `13x13x2`. Are you still using the `tuned_parameters` from above? Note that you have a capital `C` in your `C_range` in my code is `c_range`

Comment: You are right, I changed the c_range because I get the heatmap as shown in the question above :( your code is working very well, but I think there is a problem with the last visualization part of heatmap plot!?
`plt.imshow(scores_rbf,origin='lower',cmap=plt.cm.hot)
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.ylabel('gamma')
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)), gamma_range)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(c_range)), np.round(c_range,2), rotation=45)
plt.colorbar()`

Comment: I've edited my answer trying to make it cover your query regarding the plot.

Comment: Got it, I am still trying to find the best parameters. Thank you so much for your help :D

Comment: @AhmadYehia Cool glad I could help. Can I suggest you edit the title of the question to something along the lines of "SVR hyperparameter selection and visualisation". I think it will make it easier for other people to find it if they have similar questions.